# Can't load XML via jQuery from a different domain

Tags: jquery, xml, cross-domain

I've searched far and wide and tried example after example of both tutorials and solutions found around the web and still can't get this to work on my local machine or server. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Now, on to business...

I'm trying to take a feed in the form of XML on some site or server somewhere and display it on a page. Seems simple, right?  Below is my code that I'm using based on jQuery documentation...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Get XML Demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="someElement"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        var xml = $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml",
            dataType: "xml"
        })
        .done( function() {
            alert("We have XML data!");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("Failed to get XML");   
        });

        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
            $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
            $heading = $xml.find( "heading" );

        // Append "Reminder" to #someElement
        $( "#someElement" ).append( $heading.text() );

        // Change the title to "XML Title"
        $heading.text( "XML Title" );

        // Append "XML Title" to #anotherElement
        $( "#anotherElement" ).append( $heading.text() );
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems conspiring to make this not work.

**First:** You are blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Unless the site your are loading data from explicitly allows you to do this, you won't be able to load the file. If you can't get cooperation from the source of the data, you'll need to move your data loading to the server side.

Also note that in Chrome (and possibly other browsers) you cannot load data via AJAX from `file:///` URLs. So if you are opening the HTML file directly from your hard drive (such that the Location field in Chrome starts with `file:///`) and try to AJAX load another local file, it will fail.

Tip: Keep an eye on your error console. Your browser should tell you what's going on. For instance, when I run your code in Safari I get this clear error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   _display:29

The best way to test AJAX is with a local web server. If that isn't possible, consider getting a free hosting account where you can upload the HTML, XML, etc.. and test through your browser.

`jsfiddle.net` is also an option, although testing AJAX is tricky because of the same origin policy we're talking about. They have [documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) about this, but it probably introduces more complexity than you want.

Finally, I believe FireFox will let you AJAX local `file:///` URLs, so that may be an option.

You need to get to the point where your script alerts "We have XML data!". If it doesn't say that, then the AJAX request itself is failing. Again, keep an eye on the error console.

**Second:** The structure of your code is wrong for handling the AJAX response.

The "A" in AJAX stands for "Asynchronous". This means the AJAX action runs independent of the thread of execution in your script itself. So when you do this:

```
var xml = $.ajax({
   url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml",
   dataType: "xml"
});

...

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
```

The last line is executing well before the AJAX load has finished. Think of $.ajax as a "background" process. Your script will carry on while it loads.

You need to do *all* your XML processing in one of the callbacks from the jquery `ajax` call.

```
var xml = $.ajax({
   url: "note.xml",
   dataType: "xml"
})
.done( function() {
   alert("We have XML data!");
})
```

First, the $.ajax function returns a jquery `jqXHR` object, not the XML. So you don't want to assign it to your `xml` variable. Instead, you want something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "note.xml",
   dataType: "xml"
})
.done( function(data) {
   alert("We have XML data!");
   ... do all your xml processing here ...
})
```

The code inside `done` will execute *after* the ajax load finishes, and it will receive the AJAX response data as its first parameter.

Also, note that you can use the ajax `success` callback instead, which I find a little less mysterious:

```
var xml = $.ajax({
   url: "note.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(data) {
      alert("We have XML data!");
      ... your processing here ...
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert("XML failed with error: " + error);
   }
})
```

**Third:** You specify a dataType of "xml" so you don't need to parse the XML. Jquery will do this for you.

We're getting outside my comfort zone here because I never process XML in jQuery (I've done it a few times, but all my sites prefer JSON). But my vague recollection is that the `data` given to your `success` callback will be ready-to-query.

**Finally:** I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the XML data.

It looks like maybe you've adjusted the code a few times and the comments didn't keep up. I'm just assuming you want to take text from the XML and put it into the `#someElement` div.

So your final code would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "note.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(data) {
      alert("We have XML data!");
      var heading = $xml.find( "heading" );
      $( "#someElement" ).append( $heading.text() );
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert("XML failed with error: " + error);
   }
})
```

That may not be 100% correct. It is tedious to set it all up on my end so I'm going untested here. But hopefully it gets you on the right track.

Comment: That doesn't seem to match up with the tutorials I've been trying and the happy comments from people that have gotten it to work. Here is one where they access the file on their local machine: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/read-and-process-xml-using-jquery-ajax.html Even when I try to access feeds that are meant to be consumed by third parties, I still get this behavior.

Comment: In that example, the URL they're loading is `"BookList.xml"`, which is from the same server. You're loading `"http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"`. Unless you're running your code on a page served on www.w3schools.com you're script and the data don't have the same origin. See the [jquery documentation for the $.ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and search for "same origin". This is documented behavior: " the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol."

Comment: Okay, so why doesn't this work when it's on my local machine or on the same domain????????????? Also, why doesn't this work for services meant to be consumed in this manner?

Comment: Update your question with code that doesn't work but should. Hard to say without more information. But your code in the question definitely will not work because of the same origin policy.

Comment: Code change for local machine: Change url to just note.xml and download the xml from w3schools and place it in the same folder as the html file above. I really appreciate the information, I just don't have much hair left.

Comment: Ok, I looked more deeply at your code and revised my answer with lots more info. Same origin is only the first of your problems. Hang in there, this stuff is confusing but you'll get the hang of it and it will start to make sense!

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this detailed information. I've done similar actions using server side code and found myself in a situation where I needed to take an xml feed from various other domains and format them on the page without server side code. I thought I could do this with jQuery based on some of the tutorials I found but they never explained the same origin policy. Thanks again